# TDS Problem - Root Direction / My Folder: C:\tex - Should work?

Tags: installing, miktex

My Problem is that I want to include a stylesheet for LaTeX from my university. 
I have MikTeX 2.9 running.

With MiKTeX Options I should be able to add a root direction, such as

```
    MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Not a TDS-compliant root directory.  
Data: C:\localtexmf  
Source: Programs\MiKTeX\MO\MFC\PropPageRoots.cpp  
Line: 367  
MiKTeX: 2.9  
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Business Edition, 64-bit Service Pack 1 (build 7601)  
Invokers: non-existing/explorer  
SystemAdmin: yes  
PowerUser: no  
Root0: C:\Users\Chef\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9  
Root1: C:\Users\Chef\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9  
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9  
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9  
UserInstall: C:\Users\Chef\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9  
UserConfig: C:\Users\Chef\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9  
UserData: C:\Users\Chef\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9  
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9  
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9  
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

If I am also putting it for example: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\TUD`
It doesn't work

What am I doing wrong?

Any ideas?

Comment: To do a shameless copy of an own work (cf. my answer to [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex)): “This folder must be TDS compliant … MiKTeX will complain, if not. What you need, depends on what you want to install into this directory, at least a tex\latex subtree should be sufficient. You will go safe, if you mimic the structure of the (itself TDS compliant) MiKTEX tree…”

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, such a directory (I guess it corresponds to the style/class files from your university) cannot be installed directly under a root. It should be in `<root>\tex\latex\TUD`. And the `<root>` should not be `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9`, but preferably in some local TeX root that respects the TDS architecture, e.g. `C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\TUD`, creating the required directories.
You also can put them in `C:\Users\Chef\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\TUD`.

If there is any documentation, put it in `<root>\doc\latex\TUD`, whichever local root you choose.

Don't forget to refresh the FNDB.

Comment: That was it. 

I Had it an    C:\LocalTeXMF

But now I have it in     C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\TUD

Thank you very very much!

All out there, have great day!

Comment: @user10867 [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.