# Exact definition of a "local package repository" and exact associated procedures

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, texmf, folders

I spend quite a while now moving my folders containing my .sty files. They are of the kind nicepackage/nicepackage.sty , as specified in the [latex wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages#Installing_a_package)

My operating system is windows 7, and I want to use Miktex 2.9

I did try the following folder structures, from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148964/tds-problem-root-direction-my-folder-c-tex-should-work) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te) :

- C:\LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\TUD\nicepackage
- C:\Users\Chef\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\TUD\nicepackage
- C:\Users\stefan\texmf\tex\latex\nicepackage

In  all my trials, I created myself the folders named "texmf", "tex", "latex" and "TUD".

For all these configurations, I tried to define as a root for package installation in "MikTex package manager" and "MikTex settings" the folders

- tex
- latex
- texmf
- TUD
- *the corresponding parent folder*

Each time, I get an error message like "Not a TDS compliant root directory"

I cannot install the packages "on the fly" for security reasons (workplace computer).

I would like an answer giving a mathematically accurate description of a local package repository (ideally using the [notations for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)), and which package should be declared as the local package repository.

Also, if I should use any folder created during the installation of MikTex, please mention it.

A link to a guide which contains this information would also be interesting.

This would enable anyone who thinks like me to either solve this problem or determine that it comes from something else.