# How do I *automatically* set the search path for MikTeX?

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, paths

**Short version of the question**

I need to automatically (not manually) install some packages that were not included after the installation of MiKTeX 2.9. I was able to solve this problem by following [Leo Liu's responce](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30087/how-do-i-set-the-search-path-for-miktex/30089#30089), but this process is very manual... Is there a way to do the same, but using the command line? Or even better using a batch file or something similar?

**Long version of the question**

I am creating an automatic process to install MiKTeX and compile a .tex file to produce a .pdf document. This process would be used in our floor plant and implemented in all of our systems. Those systems run Windows 7 Professional 32-bit but **do NOT have internet access.** Which is why we have to bring all executables and required files in a USB-installer to the floor plant.

All the things I've tried so far:

1. At first I though that if MiKTeX was installed with the option “*Install missing packages on-the-fly:*” set to **Yes**, it would do the trick. Unfortunately, this seems to only work if there is internet connection...
2. Then I tried to create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX, as [Speravir explains here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex/69484#69484), or several others explain too. Unfortunately, just like @user5751924 [1] and others, creating a "TDS compliant root directory" seems an impossible task... This goes in conjunction with trying to use the `mpm` (MiKTeX package manager) command [2], going also nowhere. In particular, the *mpmcli_admin.log* always says "Not a package repository" when I try for example:

   `mpm --admin --install-some=list.txt --repository=C:\localtexmf`

   Here, the "*list.txt*" contains (among others) the following packages that I need to install:

   - titlesec
   - fancyhdr
   - xifthen
   - xcolor
   - tikzpagenodes
   - grffile

   All those packages were manually downloaded and added to the USB-installer, in a fashion that should be TDS compliant, but clearly something is going wrong.
3. I have also tried to consult the MiKTeX Manual but no luck there. I even looked at the PackageManager.cpp source code to try to understand what was the problem with my directory, but that was a dead end :(
4. Finally, I did the manual install from @Leo Liu's responce, and it worked in one machine! But since this process needs to be done for hundreds of machines in the floor plant, the process **must be automated**. So his response doesn't help me too much.

How can I automate a process to do this **using the command line**? Using a batch file is also acceptable. Or any other help is extremely welcome!

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

PS. I'd be happy to provide any extra information if needed...

[1] [Exact definition of a "local package repository" and exact associated procedures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357479/exact-definition-of-a-local-package-repository-and-exact-associated-procedures)

[2] https://docs.miktex.org/manual/mpm.html

Comment: Join TUG and get the TeX Collection on DVD.  I think you can even download it online (to put on a DVD), but I'm not sure if it works that way: https://www.tug.org/texcollection/, with the proTeXt segment for a MikTeX-like installation: https://www.tug.org/protext/.  The page indicates "if you have plenty of bandwidth and want to burn your own DVD, you can download proTeXt as a giant ISO image."  Disclaimer: While I have the TeX Collection DVD, I have not actually attempted an installation with it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @steven-b-segletes, it's good to know that there is this option out there. Since I don't need "the entire" TeX Collection but rather the required packages and those few others, I prefer to install them myself. Besides our systems will only compile the report I created (and nothing else) so it is a very restricted environment for the use of latex here. And this is what I want. Again, thanks for taking the time to read my post and commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

graphicx is a required package. So there should be no need to install it.

To install the other packages

### With a local repository

Get from CTAN the needed miktex packages from here

```
 http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
```

Most of the package are lzma-files, but there are also other formats.

Get also `miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma` and `miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma`. Ensure that all files are from the same ctan mirror so that the versions match.

Put everything in a folder (don't unpack the files!!) e.g. `C:\localrepository`. Then install them with

```
  mpm --admin --install-some=list.txt --repository=C:\localrepository
```

I can't know if the `--admin` switch is suitable for you. Without it mpm will install the packages in the USERINSTALL tree.

`list.txt` should contain a list of *miktex*-package names. So not `hhline` but `tools` (but this should be already installed), and not `zref` but `oberdiek`.

### With a localtexmf

Get the packages from the same source. Create a `C:\localtexmf`. Unpack the packages in this folder (e.g. 7zip can handle the lzma). Check that all files are in the correct subfolder. E.g. xcolor.sty should be in `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\xcolor`. You can view in the package manager of miktex in the properties of a package the correct path of every file:

[image]

When the localtexmf is correctly filled you can copy it to whatever location is suitable and attach it to a miktex system with

```
initexmf --register-root=C:\localtexmf
```

Again it depends on your actual setup if you should use `--admin` or not.

There are probably faster and more automatic ways to setup such a localtexmf (one can probably use mpm for it too) but imho a local repository is the more sensible solution anyway.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your response @ulrike-fischer. It is very useful and is helping to go in the right way. I still have so extra questions:

Comment: Here are the extra questions:
 1. The [link for CTAN packages](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/) does not have hhline. Any idea where I can find the lzma file for it? I really need this one on my .tex file!
 2. The Package Manager keeps complaining about `zref` just saying "MiKTeX encountered an internal error" and points to line 656 of the _PackageManager.cpp_ in the _mpmcli.log_ file. I guess this is because it does not have the package info (by looking in the GUI). Any idea how to fix this? I'm using the "**With a local repository**" part of your response.

Comment: hhline.sty is in tools and should be already installed. Regarding zref: it is in the oberdiek package. Your list.txt should be a list of miktex names, not of styles or single files.

Comment: Thanks again Ulrike. I'm now looking in the MiKTeX Package Manager GUI to find what package contains each .sty file that I need (apparently there are a LOT more than I originally thought). Such a long and tedious task... but I hope at the end I can get all required packages I need installed.